# File Compare with c#

Tags: c#, windows, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare 2 files fast using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358510/how-to-compare-2-files-fast-using-net)

How can I compare 2 sys files with same named in Dllcache and system32/drivers folders in order to sys file in system32/drivers is corrupted or not?with c#(md5 checksum or crc32 or ...)

Comment: @ken2k - Their [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343055/dllcache-folder-and-access-issue) posted today contains his attempt.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60342/how-to-answer-do-my-work-for-me-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare their [SHA1 hashes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx):

```
public string ComputeHash(string filename)
{
    using(var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        string hash = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(fileData));

    }
}
```