# Check if a folder contains a file that is a copy of a file in another folder

Tags: .net, file, directory, copy

I have a file:

```
string myFile = @"C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\myFile.txt";
```

And I want to check if there is a copy of this file in another directory:

```
string DestinationDir = @"C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\MyDir"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I know is the one that makes use of [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) and [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) classes, in the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io) namespace.

You could use the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) method  to combine the path of the your destination directory with the name of the file to find (returned by [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename) method):

```
string dest_file = Path.Combine(dest_dir, Path.GetFileName(source_file));
```

At this point you could simply check if `dest_file` exist with [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method:

```
if (File.Exists(dest_file))
{
   // You can get file properties using the FileInfo class
   FileInfo info_dest = new FileInfo(dest_file);
   FileInfo info_source = new FileInfo(source_file);

   // And to use the File.OpenRead method to create the FileStream
   // that allows you to compare the two files
   FileStream stream_dest = info_dest.OpenRead();
   FileStream stream_source = info_source.OpenRead();

   // Compare file streams here ...
}
```

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320348/en-us) an article that explains how to compare two files using FileStream.

There is also an alternative to check if the file exist in the destination directory, take a look at the [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa70yfe2) class, in particular to the method [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx):

```
foreach (string dest_file in Directory.GetFiles(dest_dir))
{
    // Compare dest_file name with source_file name
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a truly comprehensive response.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the file name from the `myFile`, use `Path.Combine` to create new path for DestinationDir + your filename and then, check if the file exists, using [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

For comparing two files try:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path, Encoding encoding)
bool same = File.ReadLines(path1).SequenceEqual(File.ReadLines(path2));
```

Check this thread: [How to compare 2 files fast using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358510/how-to-compare-2-files-fast-using-net)