# Folder/File Comparison

Tags: c#, comparison

I want to write a function that compares two **files** / **folders** to check if one of them is changed.

If there is something added/removed or changed in a file it means that some changes happen in one of them. So the function returns that provided files are not identical. This one is easy.

The hard part (if it is a folder): I want to check if two folders that has **same material**. For example:

> *Folder 1:*
>
> - testfolder (has a.txt inside)
> - testfile.txt
> - testfile2.txt
>
> *Folder 2:*
>
> - testfolder (its a.txt has different text than the other one) - changed
> - testfile.txt (same) - no change
> - testfile2.txt (same) - no change

*Output*: Function return that these two folders (Folder 1 and 2) are not the same. (Because *testfolder* inside *Folder 2* has a file that is not identical to the file in *testfolder* that is inside *Folder 1*)

How can I create such control, what is the best approach? Should I do a recursive search in all folders and check all files one by one? (Hope not) Is there a MD5 control for folders like files? What should I do?

Comment: you have 2 choices in my opinion use the [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) or [the Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do recursive comparision of folder. This should not be difficult.

As was wrote in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358510/how-to-compare-2-files-fast-using-net) the best approach of file comparison is byte-to-byte comparision. This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320348/en-us) shows how to do it.