# How to compare a pdf file on my local machine to a http response in pdf format in C#

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a pdf file on my local machine and I want to compare it with my http response which is in pdf format. I am new to this and I have no idea how to do it. Can someone please suggest how can I do it. Please find below my code:

```
/******Get the document********/
String urlDoc = "https://abcd/v1/requests/"+order.request.id+"/"+"document";
                
HttpWebRequest requestDoc = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlDoc);
requestDoc.Headers.Add("authorization", id_token);
requestDoc.Method = "GET";
                
var webResponse4 = requestDoc.GetResponse();
var webStream4 = webResponse4.GetResponseStream();
var responseReader4 = new StreamReader(webStream4);
var response4 = responseReader4.ReadToEnd();
Report.Success("Response : " + response4.ToString());
Request reqs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(response4);

// Clean up the streams.
responseReader4.Close();
```

Output of this is in pdf format.

Comment: Define "compare". Do you want to compare the bytes of the two files (i.e., make sure they're identical)? Do you want to compare the actual contents of the PDFs and make sure they "look the same"? Or do you want to compare the contents of the PDFs and generate a report of the diffs? The first has been asked and answered a million times, I'm sure. The second and third are too broad to fit into one question.

Comment: By the way, you should dispose `webResponse4` and `responseReader4` with a `using` block

Comment: Save it to disk then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358510/how-to-compare-2-files-fast-using-net

Answer (score 0):

Compare the files using [file hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_verification)

Use the MD5 file hashing method to hash files.
Use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520086/12897035)