# How to check if two files are the same .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check if the contents of a file and some words that were inputted are the same? I want to make some sort of activation system, where it will check if the contents are the same as the input.

Here's what I want to do:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Example {
  public class Example() {
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == File(@"/prodkey.txt") {
      //code
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The exact same, like a password?  Or do you mean like search where it is looking to find all of the words somewhere in the document?  As a sentence, or with the words appearing in any order>

Comment: compare checksums?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare 2 files fast using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358510/how-to-compare-2-files-fast-using-net)

Comment: Your title says "two files" but your question and code say "words that were inputted" -- which is it?  Please edit your question to add more information.

Comment: @DaveS Like a password.

Comment: @Dave S And yes, as soon as i posted it, i found out that it said "two files" instead of "words that were inputted. I forgot to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadAllText(filePath)` to get the contents of a text file, and then compare them using the `==` operator, or the `string.Equals` method (which provides for case-insensitive comparison):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"/prodkey.txt");

if (input == fileContent) 
{
  
}

// Or, for case-insensitive comparison:
if (input.Equals(fileContent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  
}
```