# .Net C# PDF files comparison not working with any method

Tags: c#, .net, file-comparison

I need to compare two PDF files for equality. The two files need to be identical in content, and I'm not having any success with the proposals found on:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36108862/2807741

```
public static bool AreFileContentsEqual(String path1, String path2) =>
              File.ReadAllBytes(path1).SequenceEqual(File.ReadAllBytes(path2));
```

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76917554/2807741

```
private bool AreFilesEqual(string file1Path, string file2Path)
{
    string file1Hash = "", file2Hash = "";
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

    using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file1Path))
    {
        byte[] hash;
        hash = sha.ComputeHash(fs);
        file1Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file2Path))
    {
        byte[] hash;
        hash = sha.ComputeHash(fs);
        file2Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    return (file1Hash == file2Hash);
}
```

(among other links I've tried).

I'm comparing two "identical" files and they're always returning false (unless I compare a file with itself, only case where it returns true).

The way I created the files to compare is the next:

1. Word > Write any content > "Save as" > PDF.
2. Keep the content intact and "Save as" > PDF (with different name)

Maybe something is changing in the second file when saving even I'm not making any modifications to it?

file1.pdf:

[image: file1.pdf]

file2.pdf

[image: file2.pdf]

Edit 1:

When I say "Identical" I mean identical in content. The PDFs will contain amounts (numbers), and those amounts in the PDF bills must be exactly the same.

Comment: "Maybe something is changing in the second file when saving even I'm not making any modifications to it?" Yes, it sounds like it. For example, it could easily contain a timestamp for "when the file was saved". It doesn't sound like the problem is within your *code* at all... but you should be able to find any number of hash/diff tools out there which would help to validate that.

Comment: Bytes and Hashes will be different as soon as you create two PDFs in two different ways. PDF is a highly complex "format". It will probably even differ if you save the very same file twice with the same tool.

Comment: What does "identical" mean in your case? Files are not identical unless they are 100% the same, bit-by-bit. Two files that contain the same content may still have different meta data, like the creation date or other meta data which can be different.

Comment: ^^ That said, _maybe_ a specialized compare-tool for PDF might be able to tell you that content is - for all intents and puposes - identical?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Julian. With identical I mean identical in content.

Comment: _"The PDFs will contain amounts (numbers), and those amounts in the PDF bills must be exactly the same."_ - Are your PDFs compliant to any electronic Payment Standard? Like ZugFerD or XRechnung or whatever is out there? If not, does it at least contain a Data-Layer?

Comment: Thanks for your help @fildor. The PDF files will contain bills, and I need the amounts (numbers) in those bills to be exactly the same. I don't mind if the metadata is different as long as all the amounts match. FYI, the two PDF files will be created with .Net in the same exact way.

Comment: If you want to compare content, you need a program that can parse the binary file and extract the content for you to compare. This is not trivial. It's likely you will need a third-party library for this.

Comment: ^^ "Diego" sounds spanish... Is that for Spain or South-America? I know in some states like Mexico there is a mandatory electronic ... "commerce" standard. Don't remember what it is called. But you definitely can extract all Billing info from the data layers and then, of course, compare that.

Comment: Thanks for your help @John Wu. I'm quite sure I'll need a library in the end, but I've only found https://github.com/menees/Diff.Net and it only works for desktop apps, as far as I've seen.

Comment: You will not succeed on a file-based level. You need to introspect them. No way around that.

Comment: No @Fildor, the "Bills" in the pdf doesn't come from any payment method, they're just generated by one of our apps I don't even know how yet, I was asked to compare the contents of two PDF files for amounts matching in a .Net Test project method.

Comment: Oooof.. That's ... well: Having done work in that field for several years, I can only suggest to **not role your own pdf billing format**. There _is_ a matching officially supported / endorsed e-billing format for your jurisdiction. Use it. There will be toolchains for it. Generators, validators, libraries, documentation ... name it.

Comment: If you cannot push back to using one of those, push back on an internal standard that includes an extractable data-layer in a specific agreed-upon format. Everything else (given, still using PDF) will in some way or another _not work_.

Comment: If they in fact do use one of those formats _and didn't tell you_: they should have and it wasn't nice not to. But it may have not been intentional. Maybe just ask how the PDFs come to pass exactly.

Comment: PDFs contain metadata such as Creation Date + Modification date + Document UUID. These will be different every time a file is created, and a binary compare will always show differences. The only ways are around this are (a) make the *Generator app* not output such fields -or- make it set them to specific values, or (b) parse the PDFs and look at their contents, which could be quite a challenging task.

Comment: @PeterB In comments above we established that the PDFs are actually bills and the payment data is what shall actually be compared. OP should [edit] the question to reflect that, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer myself. **iText7** is the way to go, as it can read PDF files content as text.

Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var exeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    var workPath = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFilePath)}\\Assets";

    var file1 = $"{workPath}\\testpdfv1.pdf";
    var file2a = $"{workPath}\\testpdfv2equalv1.pdf";
    var file2b = $"{workPath}\\testpdfv2differentv1.pdf";

    var fileContents1 = PdfToText(file1);
    var fileContents2 = PdfToText(file2a);

    var filesAreEqual = fileContents1 == fileContents2;

    return View();
}

private string PdfToText(string pPdfFileInfo)
{
    var pdfFileInfo = new FileInfo(pPdfFileInfo);
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFileInfo.FullName));
    var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    var result = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
    {
        var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
        string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
        result += text;
    }
    pdfDocument.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're doing 2 times `PdfToText(file1)` ...